# CSV Import to Excel from MySQL leaves "/" at end of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv, phpmyadmin

After exporting my sql query to a csv file, more specifically the "CSV for Excel" format from phpMyAdmin, the dates are properly saved in quotes. Ex: `"1990-01-30"`. The delimiter is `;`. However, when I import the file to Excel, all the dates, except the last date last record, end in a "/".

MySQL Date: `1990-01-30`

Import to Excel via csv

Excel Date: `1990-01-30/`

Last Date Last Record: `1952-12-24}` (Note the })

How do I fix this without manually fixing each date?

Comment: Might be an idea to show a few lines from the CSV file.

Comment: You may select column and just replace (ctrl-H) "/" with "" (empty string), then change that column date to "date" format.

Answer (score 0):

This will strip the last character off the text, and turn it into a date value

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))
```

- DateValue returns the value in excel's usual number format - format the cells as a date to see the dates
- The last date will still work, as the formula does not care what the extra character is